# checkBalance(ref bool) not all code paths return a value?

Tags: c#, boolean

I have just started learning C# so am pretty new... I am trying to write the method for Check balance but keep getting the error i said in the title... i know the code is not finished but just wanted to be able to return the Account Types menu for the moment??

Also is someone able to explain the line  "static void start(ref bool dimensionsUpdated)" I don't really know what this does. Thankyou!!

```
class Program
{
   static void start(ref bool dimensionsUpdated){
        int userOption = 0;

        //Repeats the loop until the user wishes to exit
        do
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to EziTeller ATM Machine\n\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Transaction Menu"
                        + "\n================\n"
                        + "\n1) Check Balance"
                        + "\n2) Withdraw"
                        + "\n3) Transfer");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease Enter Your Option: 1, 2, 3 or 0 to exit: ");

        //Read in the users choice
        userOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.ReadKey(); 

            //Run a series of checks to see what the user chose.
            //Open the desired method, otherwise show error message
            //Asking the user to input a VALID option.
            if (userOption == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using EziTeller!");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else if (userOption == 1){
                checkBalance(ref dimensionsUpdated);
            }
            else if (userOption == 2){
                withdrawMoney(ref dimensionsUpdated);
            }
            else if (userOption == 3){
                transferMoney(ref dimensionsUpdated);
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease enter a valid option, either 1, 2, 3, or 0 to exit\n\n");
        }   while (userOption != 0);
   }
    public static double checkBalance(ref bool dimensionsUpdated){
        Console.WriteLine("Account Types"
                        + "\n============\n"
                        + "\n1) Savings Account"
                        + "\n2) Debit Card"
                        + "\n3) Credit Card"
                        + "\n4) Line of Credit");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease Enter Your Option: 1...4 or 0 to exit: ");
```

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions at a time. Could you break those up into two separate SO questions, please?

Comment: I mainly want to know why I get the error checkBalance(ref bool) not all code paths return a value?

Comment: Please post at least enough code so we can see how the `checkBalance` method ends then.

Comment: That's all the code I have so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your method is returning a `double` value and you are not returning anything from your method.

```
public static double checkBalance(ref bool dimensionsUpdated)
```

Since the complete code is not present in the question, you may post complete code.

May be you are returning a `double` values inside an `if statement`, if so, you need to make sure that any of your method path should return a double value.

Or if that is the complete code of your `checkBalance` method and you are not returning anything from it then you may change the method signature to return `void`

```
public static void checkBalance(ref bool dimensionsUpdated)
```

Comment: For the check balance method I want it to display the different account types then by selecting different accounts display the $value in that account (set values)... to do this would I use double or void?

Comment: @user1645218, if you are only displaying the result and not returning anything in your `checkBalance` method, then have `void` type.

Answer (score 0):

you can put `return 0;` at the end of `checkBalance` (temporarily) to disable the error.

What is going is that c# thinks you have a error if you declare the function as returning a double but you don't actually return anything.

Answer (score 0):

checkBalance function should return value in any cases.

```
public static double checkBalance(ref bool dimensionsUpdated){
    if(...){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(...){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do some reading about [the basics of object orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programminghttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

To answer your questions:

- Your method `checkBalance` doesn't seem to return a value although its signature states, that it would return a number of type "double". But we can't know for sure, because the end of the method is cut off in the code you posted.
- `static void start(ref bool dimensionsUpdated)` is another method declaration for a method named "start" of return type "void" (i.e. it returns nothing). It has one [reference parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) of type "boolean" named "dimensionsUpdated"